Is there a definition of division for any (inc. non-abelian) group?
I'm reading wikipedia group and there is a part titled "Division" within "Elementary consequences of the group axioms" which confusingly (to me at least) defines "left" and "right multiplication" (
or "translation") by a⁠, but does not have "division" explicitly defined, in footnote mentions:

One usually avoids using fraction notation ⁠$b/a$⁠ unless $G$ is abelian, because of the ambiguity of whether it means $a^{-1} ⋅ b$ or $b ⋅ a^{-1}$

I could not find definition of division (expecting some "left/right division") neither by web seach not in referenced book "Michael Artin - Algebra".
So am I correct to reason division is not defined unless the group is abelian? Might be useful to add that statement to wiki in such case.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)#Abstract_algebra for an abstract definition in the absence of commutativity and inverses. Basically, the left- or right division of $b$ and $a$ is the (generally required to be unique) solution to $ax=b$ or $xa=b$.

@Milten, thank you. I think wiki page on "group" would benefit from this link to be added in "Division" section.

My speculation as to why you can't find much on the web is that the term "division" is reserved for rings. Since a ring is also an abelian group with respect to the additive operation, it would be confusing to have two "divisions", one coming from the additive abelian group and the other from the multiplicative magma.

@Milten, I think your comment could be an answer which I can accept since it has link to source (one answer here does not have it). But if you are not interested in that, I could try to communicate your link to already written answer.

Anyone can define left division ($b^{-1} a$) and right division ($ab^{-1}$), and a concerted literature search might well come up with papers and/or books where someone has done this. On the one hand, this is rarely done because it is rarely useful for anything, and for that reason it would not be advisable to add it to the wiki page. On the other hand, one cannot assert that there is no paper in the mathematical literature where someone has used it for something and therefore defined it.

@LeeMosher If not add to wiki page, how this section will be left named "Divsion"? Or do you suggest changing it to ....?

In algebra, instead of being a primary notion, division is defined through multiplication by the inverse as shown, for example, in en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)#Abstract_algebra .
If the multiplication is Abelian, division is defined unambigously:
$$a/b := a\cdot b^{-1}.$$
Since, from this perspective, division is merely a secondary notion, it is often omitted.
For non-Abelian multiplications, one does need to specify whether left or right division is intended. The convention used above, called right division, would guarantee that
$$(a/b)\cdot b = a.$$
For left division, the order is reversed:
$$b\backslash a := b^{-1}\cdot a.$$
However, when multiplication is assumed to be associative, these two operations are compatible and the expression $$c\backslash a/b = c^{-1}\cdot a\cdot b^{-1}$$ is unambiguous. It does not matter whether one first performs left division, or first right division.

In wiki in "Division" "Given elements a and b of a group ⁠G ⁠, there is a unique solution x in G to the equation ⁠ a ⋅ x = b ⁠, namely ⁠ a^(− 1) ⋅ b.". I only wonder if it is formally called left division. Preferably with a source ref from a math book.

What i wrote down is formally (usually) called right division. I have edit my answer

I need links to edit wiki. If you agree with comment posted to my question with link to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)#Abstract_algebra, please add link somewhere to your answer and then I think I can accept your answer.

The other division is $b\backslash a = b^{-1} \cdot a$. Notice that the two are compatible, so $b\backslash a / c$ unambiguously means $b^{-1} \cdot a \cdot c^{-1}$. There is no need to decide between these as the answer unfortunately suggests.

@MartinBrandenburg, do you mean there is no need for / sign to be ambiguous? Cause you notation still looks as differentiate left and right.

Martin means that it does not matter whether you first do left division or first do right division. This makes expressions unambiguous, but still requires that distinct notations are used.

@NDewolf,  where is in the answer "first do left division"? I see no line with both divisions.

@Martian2020 I added these things to my answer for future clarity

There is no official standards body for mathematics so many questions about definitions just don't have answers.
Division is a convenient practical operation when working with real and complex numbers but it is not a fundamental operation that attracts more abstract study.  It is just shorthand for multiplication by the inverse.
An odd example is division ring - this is a ring in which all non-zero elements have multiplicative inverses and hence division is possible.  This is sometimes called a skew field as it is a field without the requirement of multiplication being commutative.  An example is the quaternions.  The oddity is that despite being called a division ring, it is still not typical to talk of division.
If you want to discuss division in non-commutative groups or rings then go ahead but add a note indicating what you mean by $a/b$.

The study of algebra (in the sense of algebraic structures, like groups and fields and rings etc) focuses on the binary operations addition and multiplication (at least at the undergrad level). Subtraction and division are generally just considered as composing those operations with unary inversion ie mapping an element to its additive or multiplicative inverse, and then adding or multiplying with that element. Note that because addition is nearly always taken to be commutative, subtraction still makes sense. otoh, as you note, division doesn't work once you don't have a commutative multiplication, and that's the interesting case, so we just don't talk about it.
I'm sure someone somewhere cares about division, but in general, algebra doesn't.
